# how to customize the delimiter in std::getline

Tags: c++, string, arguments, delimiter, istringstream

I was solving attribute parser on hackerRank but I am stuck with delimiter. I want to grab an element from ("any thing"), in this case it will give me (any thing), but when I do this:

```
while (getline(ob, item, '""')) {//but its be true when i put single one ('"')
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }
```

It gives me this error:

> E0304 no instance of "getline" matches the argument list

Comment: `'\"'` is the double quote character, properly escaped.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you don't need to escape a double-quote `"` inside of a char literal (single-quotes `'...'`), only inside a string literal (double-quotes `"..."`, if a raw string literal is not used)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good to know, thanks! If I had a dollar for all those extra backslashes I've typed over the years. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja well, now that we have raw literals, you never have to type them ever again.

Answer (score 1):

As @RetiredNinja said, you can use `'\"'` as the delimiter. The code may look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str, '\"'))
        if (!str.empty() && str[0] != '(' && str[0] != ')')
            std::cout << '(' << str << ")\n";
}
```

You can change the code based on the rules of the problem. Note that the delimiter would give you `"("` first, then the actual word and so on. So you'd have to filter the values you're not interested in.